# Saving color composite as TIFF in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I made a color composite using `Raster > Miscellaneous > Build Virtual Raster` in QGIS. The output is a VRT file but I need TIFF. Then I went through `Raster > Conversion > Translate`. The output is TIFF however the software automatically change the order of bands and then the output TIFF file has different color. How can I fix that?

Comment: If you access the **Build Virtual Raster** tool from the _Processing Toolbox_, you can specify the output file type. The default (atleast for me) is a .tif file but I barely ever used this tool before so am unsure if it will solve your problem :)

Comment: No mine save as VRT not TIFF

Comment: Perhaps I have a different version of the _Processing_ plugin, (I'm using 2.9.2).

Answer (score 2):

Use:
Raster>Miscellaneous>Merge...

A vrt is a catalogue to you existing files. Like a bookmark pointing to multiple files.

The Merge function will actually combine them into one .tif file.

You can change your RGB bands by going into the layer properties>Style>And selecting the bands that you want associated with each colour.